# Android Application crashes when it tries to retrieve and display GPS coordinates

Tags: android, gps

i'm building a simple application that displays the current latitude and longitude of the user, but it crashes when it tries to show GPS coordinates on an emulator and when it tries to retrieve coordinates on a real device, i've been looking for an answer and still can find one

```
public class Locator extends ActionBarActivity {
 TextView textLat;
 TextView textLong;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    textLat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLat);
    textLong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLong);
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener ll = new locatorlistener();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_locator);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) 
    {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
class locatorlistener implements LocationListener
{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location != null)
        {
            double pLong = location.getLongitude();
            double pLat = location.getLatitude();
            textLat.setText(Double.toString(pLat));
            textLong.setText(Double.toString(pLong));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_locator);
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.locator, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_locator,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

logcat:

```
06-30 05:01:49.079: D/dalvikvm(781): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 268K, 11% free 3016K/3364K, paused 339ms, total 339ms
06-30 05:01:49.829: I/InputDispatcher(379): Window 'Window{b3f05bf8 u0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}' spent 2082.7ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(deviceId=0, source=0x00001002, action=0, flags=0x00000000, metaState=0x00000000, buttonState=0x00000000, edgeFlags=0x00000000, xPrecision=1.0, yPrecision=1.0, displayId=0, pointers=[0: (428.0, 370.0)]), policyFlags=0x42000000
06-30 05:01:49.869: I/Choreographer(536): Skipped 720 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-30 05:01:49.889: I/InputDispatcher(379): Window 'Window{b3f05bf8 u0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}' spent 2138.6ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(deviceId=0, source=0x00001002, action=2, flags=0x00000000, metaState=0x00000000, buttonState=0x00000000, edgeFlags=0x00000000, xPrecision=1.0, yPrecision=1.0, displayId=0, pointers=[0: (427.0, 370.0)]), policyFlags=0x42000000
06-30 05:01:49.889: I/InputDispatcher(379): Window 'Window{b3f05bf8 u0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}' spent 2121.0ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(deviceId=0, source=0x00001002, action=2, flags=0x00000000, metaState=0x00000000, buttonState=0x00000000, edgeFlags=0x00000000, xPrecision=1.0, yPrecision=1.0, displayId=0, pointers=[0: (428.0, 371.0)]), policyFlags=0x42000000
06-30 05:01:49.909: I/InputDispatcher(379): Window 'Window{b3f05bf8 u0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}' spent 2077.7ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(deviceId=0, source=0x00001002, action=2, flags=0x00000000, metaState=0x00000000, buttonState=0x00000000, edgeFlags=0x00000000, xPrecision=1.0, yPrecision=1.0, displayId=0, pointers=[0: (427.0, 372.0)]), policyFlags=0x42000000
06-30 05:01:49.909: I/InputDispatcher(379): Window 'Window{b3f05bf8 u0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}' spent 2000.4ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(deviceId=0, source=0x00001002, action=2, flags=0x00000000, metaState=0x00000000, buttonState=0x00000000, edgeFlags=0x00000000, xPrecision=1.0, yPrecision=1.0, displayId=0, pointers=[0: (426.0, 374.0)]), policyFlags=0x42000000
06-30 05:01:50.779: D/dalvikvm(536): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2813K, 30% free 7068K/9992K, paused 140ms, total 154ms
06-30 05:01:50.989: E/memtrack(1104): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
06-30 05:01:51.009: E/android.os.Debug(1104): failed to load memtrack module: -2
06-30 05:01:51.259: D/dalvikvm(536): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 72K, 17% free 8360K/9992K, paused 66ms, total 68ms
06-30 05:01:51.889: I/ActivityManager(379): Delay finish: com.android.settings/.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider
06-30 05:01:52.079: I/Choreographer(536): Skipped 547 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-30 05:01:52.429: D/dalvikvm(536): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1598K, 28% free 7248K/9992K, paused 78ms, total 83ms
06-30 05:01:52.579: I/Choreographer(536): Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-30 05:01:52.919: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
06-30 05:01:52.919: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
06-30 05:01:52.929: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
06-30 05:01:52.929: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
06-30 05:01:52.929: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
06-30 05:01:52.929: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
06-30 05:01:52.929: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
06-30 05:01:52.929: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
06-30 05:01:53.069: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
06-30 05:01:53.069: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
06-30 05:01:53.069: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
06-30 05:01:53.099: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
06-30 05:01:53.109: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
06-30 05:01:53.129: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
06-30 05:01:53.129: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
06-30 05:01:53.189: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
06-30 05:01:53.219: I/ActivityManager(379): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.trucktracker/.MainActivity} from pid 536
06-30 05:01:53.239: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
06-30 05:01:53.259: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
06-30 05:01:53.299: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
06-30 05:01:53.319: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
06-30 05:01:53.319: W/AudioService(379): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
06-30 05:01:53.599: D/gralloc(50): Registering a buffer in the process that created it. This may cause memory ordering problems.
06-30 05:01:53.599: E/libEGL(50): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
06-30 05:01:53.609: E/libEGL(50): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
06-30 05:01:53.609: E/libEGL(50): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
06-30 05:01:53.609: E/libEGL(50): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
06-30 05:01:53.609: E/SurfaceFlinger(50): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error 186238714
06-30 05:01:53.609: E/SurfaceFlinger(50): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
06-30 05:01:53.609: E/libEGL(50): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
06-30 05:01:53.609: E/libEGL(50): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
06-30 05:01:53.669: W/WindowManager(379): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (246x410) to layer 21005
06-30 05:01:53.839: I/Choreographer(536): Skipped 178 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-30 05:01:53.999: D/dalvikvm(536): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 193K, 15% free 8518K/9992K, paused 63ms, total 69ms
06-30 05:01:54.109: D/dalvikvm(379): JIT unchain all for threadid=41
06-30 05:01:54.549: D/dalvikvm(379): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 714K, 20% free 5737K/7140K, paused 684ms, total 685ms
06-30 05:01:54.619: W/ActivityManager(379): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{b3f886b8 u0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher t1}
06-30 05:01:54.959: I/Choreographer(379): Skipped 60 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-30 05:01:55.019: I/ActivityManager(379): Start proc com.example.trucktracker for activity com.example.trucktracker/.MainActivity: pid=1120 uid=10052 gids={50052}
06-30 05:01:55.159: D/dalvikvm(1120): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
06-30 05:01:56.559: I/ARMAssembler(50): generated scanline__00000077:03010104_00008001_00000000 [ 89 ipp] (110 ins) at [0xb5e0d680:0xb5e0d838] in 10000000 ns
06-30 05:01:56.679: I/Choreographer(379): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-30 05:01:56.899: I/Choreographer(379): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-30 05:01:57.829: D/dalvikvm(1120): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 64K, 5% free 3135K/3280K, paused 61ms, total 63ms
06-30 05:01:57.829: I/dalvikvm-heap(1120): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.766MB for 659360-byte allocation
06-30 05:01:57.919: D/dalvikvm(1120): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 4% free 3772K/3924K, paused 77ms, total 77ms
06-30 05:01:58.069: D/com.example.trucktracker.MainActivity(1120): Settings Text.
06-30 05:01:58.479: D/com.example.trucktracker.MainActivity(1120): Showing menu.
06-30 05:01:58.619: D/gralloc_goldfish(1120): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-30 05:01:58.779: I/ActivityManager(379): Displayed com.example.trucktracker/.MainActivity: +3s944ms
06-30 05:01:59.079: I/Choreographer(379): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-30 05:01:59.619: D/dalvikvm(930): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 324K, 13% free 2959K/3364K, paused 67ms, total 330ms
06-30 05:01:59.699: E/StrictMode(930): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
06-30 05:01:59.699: E/StrictMode(930): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'release' not called
06-30 05:01:59.699: E/StrictMode(930):  at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
06-30 05:01:59.699: E/StrictMode(930):  at android.drm.DrmManagerClient.<init>(DrmManagerClient.java:258)
06-30 05:01:59.699: E/StrictMode(930):  at com.google.android.mms.pdu.PduPersister.<init>(PduPersister.java:288)
06-30 05:01:59.699: E/StrictMode(930):  at com.google.android.mms.pdu.PduPersister.getPduPersister(PduPersister.java:296)
06-30 05:01:59.699: E/StrictMode(930):  at com.android.mms.transaction.TransactionService.onNewIntent(TransactionService.java:224)
06-30 05:01:59.699: E/StrictMode(930):  at com.android.mms.transaction.TransactionService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(TransactionService.java:621)
06-30 05:01:59.699: E/StrictMode(930):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-30 05:01:59.699: E/StrictMode(930):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-30 05:01:59.699: E/StrictMode(930):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
06-30 05:01:59.859: I/ActivityManager(379): Resuming delayed broadcast
06-30 05:01:59.959: E/BluetoothAdapter(509): Bluetooth binder is null
06-30 05:02:00.279: D/com.example.trucktracker.MainActivity(1120): ClickedContinueButton
06-30 05:02:00.299: I/ActivityManager(379): START u0 {cmp=com.example.trucktracker/.Locator} from pid 1120
06-30 05:02:00.329: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
06-30 05:02:00.329: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
06-30 05:02:00.339: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
06-30 05:02:00.339: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
06-30 05:02:00.339: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
06-30 05:02:00.339: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
06-30 05:02:00.339: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
06-30 05:02:00.339: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
06-30 05:02:00.339: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
06-30 05:02:00.359: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
06-30 05:02:00.359: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
06-30 05:02:00.359: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
06-30 05:02:00.399: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
06-30 05:02:00.399: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
06-30 05:02:00.399: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
06-30 05:02:00.409: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
06-30 05:02:00.409: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
06-30 05:02:00.409: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
06-30 05:02:00.409: E/SoundPool(379): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
06-30 05:02:00.409: W/AudioService(379): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
06-30 05:02:00.409: W/AudioService(379): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
06-30 05:02:00.599: I/Choreographer(1120): Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-30 05:02:01.909: I/Choreographer(1120): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-30 05:02:02.519: D/AlertReceiver(957): onReceive: a=android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED Intent { act=android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED dat=content://com.android.calendar flg=0x10 cmp=com.android.calendar/.alerts.AlertReceiver }
06-30 05:02:02.649: I/ActivityManager(379): Delay finish: com.android.calendar/.alerts.AlertReceiver
06-30 05:02:02.769: D/AlertService(957): 0 Action = android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED
06-30 05:02:03.309: I/Choreographer(379): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-30 05:02:03.349: I/ActivityManager(379): Displayed com.example.trucktracker/.Locator: +2s964ms
06-30 05:02:03.729: I/Choreographer(379): Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-30 05:02:04.129: I/Choreographer(536): Skipped 107 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-30 05:02:04.149: W/RecognitionManagerService(379): no available voice recognition services found for user 0
06-30 05:02:07.779: I/GlobalDismissManager(957): no sender configured
06-30 05:02:07.779: D/AlertService(957): Beginning updateAlertNotification
06-30 05:02:07.889: D/AlertService(957): No fired or scheduled alerts
06-30 05:02:08.019: D/AlertService(957): Scheduling next alarm with AlarmScheduler. sEventReminderReceived: null
06-30 05:02:08.099: D/AlarmScheduler(957): No events found starting within 1 week.
06-30 05:02:08.119: I/ActivityManager(379): Resuming delayed broadcast
06-30 05:02:08.239: I/ActivityManager(379): Delay finish: com.android.mms/.transaction.SmsReceiver
06-30 05:02:08.259: V/SmsReceiverService(930): onStart: #1 mResultCode: -1 = Activity.RESULT_OK
06-30 05:02:08.479: I/ActivityManager(379): Resuming delayed broadcast
06-30 05:02:08.569: I/ActivityManager(379): Delay finish: com.android.providers.calendar/.CalendarProviderBroadcastReceiver
06-30 05:02:08.699: I/ActivityManager(379): Resuming delayed broadcast
06-30 05:02:08.919: V/AlarmClock(983): AlarmInitReceiver android.intent.action.TIME_SET
06-30 05:02:09.209: I/AlarmClock(983): Displaying next alarm time: ''
06-30 05:02:09.279: V/AlarmClock(983): AlarmInitReceiver finished
06-30 05:02:09.409: I/ActivityManager(379): Delay finish: com.android.providers.calendar/.CalendarProviderBroadcastReceiver
06-30 05:02:09.529: I/ActivityManager(379): Resuming delayed broadcast
06-30 05:02:09.629: W/ContextImpl(1058): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1479 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 com.android.keychain.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver.onReceive:12 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver:2419 
06-30 05:02:09.669: I/ActivityManager(379): Delay finish: com.android.keychain/.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver
06-30 05:02:09.789: I/ActivityManager(379): Resuming delayed broadcast
06-30 05:02:55.079: D/LightsService(379): Excessive delay setting light: 55ms
```

Comment: can you post the logcat output.

Comment: Where have you added the TextViews ??? in activity_main or frsgment_msin.xml ???

Comment: added the logcat; changed the order of the code fixed the crashing but now it wont display the coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to see the problem, we need to see the stacktrace. But what I see is that You´ve added Your textViews before setContentView. This will not work, change it to:

```
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_locator);
      textLat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLat);
      textLong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLong);
      LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
      LocationListener ll = new locatorlistener();
      lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
```

Answer (score 2):

### Mistake:

You are trying to find Views before setting content layout.

```
textLat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLat);     <<<<<<<
textLong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLong);
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener ll = new locatorlistener();
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_locator);   <<<<<<
```

### Correct:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_locator);
textLat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLat);
textLong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLong);
....
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
textLat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLat);
textLong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLong);
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener ll = new locatorlistener();
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_locator);
```

to:

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_locator);
        textLat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLat);
        textLong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLong);
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener ll = new locatorlistener();
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_locator);
```

You are calling findViewById() of the textviews without initialising layout for your java file.That will give NPE.